# mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1406 (22001): Data too long for column

Tags: python, mysql, pdf, blob

I have a problem with storing in MySQL db a PDF file made with Reportlab library.  Here's my code:

```
def insertIntoDb(pdfFullPath,name,surname,gravity):
  print('PRIMA DEL MYSQL')
  print('pdf full path'+pdfFullPath)
  mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="deepface")
  with open(pdfFullPath,'rb') as pdfvar:
     blob = pdfvar.read()
     print(blob)
     sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO diagnosi(name,surname,pdf,gravity) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
     mycursor = mydb.cursor()
     val = (name,surname,blob,gravity,)
     mycursor.execute(sqlQuery,val)
     mydb.commit()
     mycursor.close()
     mydb.close()
```

The console says:

> mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'pdf' at row 1

I have already set max allowed packet in mysql configuration file, but the problem is that when I try to print (I know that i can't) the PDF I get this:

```
^\\7:[,1qq,N_Sd$dm-:XU2/Pga=O1f/`hY7X1nrca).:_\'-4,n*"L5r,CHFpGo:"E,MDLu7EW%CFF0$Rl?jT\'6%k%,?AF%UK6ojt/c$<^Xh=;VarY:L8cQYTgj/:CfA/j1=dbU@a<:%D;rDV[)WDu)5*"98A5kkfYAqs0FFVZk[*Mb(Rs?hIk
```

and another things, how i can store in my db?
I tried to decode with b64 but doesn't work.

```sql
> SHOW CREATE TABLE diagnosi;

diagnosi | CREATE TABLE `diagnosi` (
  `tempId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `pdf` blob NOT NULL,
  `gravity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tempId`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL `BLOB` datatype is limited to 2<sup>16</sup> bytes in size.  The `LONGBLOB` datatype can be up to 2<sup>32</sup> bytes, so change the column type from `BLOB` to `LONGBLOB`.

See the storage requirements for string types in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings).